# INSERT Statement in SQL Server Strips Characters, but using nchar(xxx) works - why?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert

I have to store some strange characters in my SQL Server DB which are used by an Epson Receipt Printer code page.

Using an `INSERT` statement, all are stored correctly except one - `[SCI]` (nchar(154)). I realise that this is a control character that isn't representable in a string, but the character is replaced by a '`?`' in the stored DB string, suggesting that it is being parsed (unsuccessfully) somewhere.

The collation of the database is **LATIN1_GENERAL_CI_AS** so it should be able to cope with it.

So, for example, if I run this `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO Table(col1) VALUES ('abc[SCI]123')
```

Where `[SCI]` is the character, a resulting `SELECT` query will return '`abc?123`'.

However, if I use `NCHAR(154)`, by directly inserting or by using a `REPLACE` command such as:

```
UPDATE Table SET col1 = REPLACE(col1, '?', NCHAR(154))
```

The character is stored correctly.

My question is, why? And how can I store it directly from an `INSERT` statement? The latter is preferable as I am writing from an existing application that produces the `INSERT` statement that I don't really want to have to change.

Thank you in advance for any information that may be useful.

Comment: You are not passing it a unicode string, try this `N'abc[SCI]123'`

Comment: Oh for crying out loud! Thank you @DavidG - I knew it'd be something stupid - that's exactly it, thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write a literal string in SQL is is created as a `VARCHAR` unless you prefix is with `N`. This means if you include any Unicode characters, they will be removed. Instead write your INSERT statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table(col1) VALUES (N'abc[SCI]123')
```